# LOAD TABLE statement with NULLable dates

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

I m looking to do a batch load into a table, called temp_data, where some of the columns are NULLable dates.

Here is what I have till now:

```
LOAD TABLE some.temp_data 
(SomeIntegerColumn ',', SomeDateColumn DATE('YYYYMMDD') NULL('NULL'), FILLER(1), SomeStringColumn ',') 
USING CLIENT FILE '{0}' ESCAPES OFF DELIMITED BY ',' ROW DELIMITED BY '#'
```

and I m trying to load the following file

```
500,NULL,Monthly#
500,NULL,Monthly#
500,NULL,Monthly#
```

Unfortunately the error I get is:

> ERROR [07006] [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Cannot convert NULL,Mon
>   to a date (column SomeDateColumn)

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's reading the 8 characters following the first delimiter and trying to interpret them as a date.

Try switching to FORMAT BCP. The following example could work on your sample file:

```
LOAD TABLE some.temp_data (
    SomeIntegerColumn
  , SomeDateColumn NULL('NULL')
  , SomeStringColumn
) 
USING CLIENT FILE '{0}'
ESCAPES OFF
DELIMITED BY ','
ROW DELIMITED BY '#'
FORMAT BCP
```

In addition,`FORMAT BCP` also has the advantage of not requiring trailing delimiters.

Comment: I was also able to get it to work by changing `FILLER(1)` to `FILLER(',')` in your original query.